# Flutter TextButton padding

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter2.0

With the Flutter 2.0 release, the `FlatButton` has been replaced with `TextButton`.

Hence, the padding property is not longer available directly, but as a `ButtonStyle` property.

My problem is, how can I set it since it's no longer available as `EdgeInsets`?

```dart
TextButton(
   style: new ButtonStyle(
     padding: ???,
   ),
   //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),   //NOT AVAILABLE
   child: Text("Support", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2),
      onPressed: () => {Navigator.pushNamed(context, SupportScreen().routeName)},
   ),
```

Comment: please mark it as answer for other users if I helped you

Comment: @MarcelDz it's a working example, so I've upvoted your answer. Yet, I'm also looking for a standard Style definition, rather than a styleFrom. Thank you once again

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is my code for TextButton

```
Container(
    child: TextButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor:
            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
            EdgeInsets.all(10)),
    ),
    child: Text(
        "Login",
        style: TextStyle(
        height: 1.0,
        fontSize: 30,
        color: Colors.white,
        ),
    ),
    onPressed: () => {print("login")},
    ),  
),
```

see I used the style property for the TextButton Widget to insert the padding and the background
and for both I used MaterialStateProperty.all

Answer (score 11):

You can do it like this for example:

```
TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Hello World'),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                primary: Colors.teal,
              ),
            ),
```

**TextButton.styleFrom() ref doc:**
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html

**example and playarounds with new button:**
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-textbutton-widget-examples

Answer (score 3):

You may set different values for MaterialStates:

```
class TextButtonPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  EdgeInsets _getPadding(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    const interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
      MaterialState.pressed,
      MaterialState.hovered,
    };
    if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
      return EdgeInsets.all(30.0);
    }
    return EdgeInsets.zero;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(_getPadding),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'Text Button',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or set one value for all MaterialStates:

```
class TextButtonPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'Text Button',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html